# url parameter passing phone number e.g. +1234 , how to retrieve it e.g. abc.com/save/xyz/+123

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, url-parameters

We have URL in which we are passing name and phone number
e.g. abc.com/save/xyz/+123

this url is coming from client so we can't change it but how can I retrieve it in backend?
I have tried every possible way but Can't find a solution. If I remove + from the phone number then it works but I can't remove + sign from the URL.

In controller, I have a function for e.g.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Save(string name,string phoneNo)
{
...
}
```

Please let me know what should I do so phone number can be access through phone no.

Comment: In a url, `+` means space. If it isn't escaped, your url actually looks like `abc.com/save/xyz/ 123`. Try accessing `Request.Url` and see if it contains the undecoded url.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen but we are redirecting from other application  with that url in my application? How should I check then?

Comment: @Ana fix it in that other application, because obviously there's the error of not url-encoding. if you don't have access to it, tell your client to fix it or you can't continue working. or implement a dirty hack by replacing `" "` with `"+"` and hope no later dev in that project curses you for it

Comment: You do not have parameters.  Parameters for URL are after a question mark.  See : https://www.searchenginejournal.com/technical-seo/url-parameter-handling/#close

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check with this

You need to add `Attribute Routing`

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Save/{name}/{phoneNo}")]
public ActionResult Save(string name,string phoneNo)
{

}
```

For more detail please check
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/